# What morphological opening will do with disk size zero

Tags: image-processing, image-morphology

Sorry for stupid question, I am using erosion followed by dilation on my image ,with disk as a structuring element.which type of noise it will remove if i use disk with size Zero ?  , or it will do nothing ? (but i observed by applying it on some images it affect them ).
Is it, removing the impulse noise ? (my guess ,as per my understanding).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its to a programming question

Comment: @martinclayton: actually such an operation is meaningless according to theory. But specific libraries may have implemented a particular policy to deal with this case - which makes a little more a programming question. But the OP gave no context.

Comment: More information would be helpful, including: your programming language, your morphology function (if you are using one from a standard library), and an example of an image on which you see an effect.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of erosion, you take the minimum of all pixels in the structuring element.

---

Strictly speaking, a disk of zero size has no pixel so that the expected result should be +infinity.